# webpack v5 configuration error: fallback parameter does not match the schema

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-5

what is wrong with my webpack-partial config in webpack v5? I have no clue why I'm getting an error about the fallback parameter when the docs explicitly say it is included [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvefallback). All my logs when the webpack partial is loaded say I am using webpack 5.82.1

ERR

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using 

a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
- configuration.resolve has an unknown property 'fallback'. These properties are valid:
object { alias?, aliasFields?, cachePredicate?, cacheWithContext?, concord?, descriptionFiles?, 
enforceExtension?, enforceModuleExtension?, extensions?, fileSystem?, mainFields?, mainFiles?, 
moduleExtensions?, modules?, plugins?, resolver?, roots?, symlinks?, unsafeCache?, useSyncFileSystemCalls? }
```

err log file contents:

```
at Object.webpack [as webpackFactory] (C:\Users\i\Desktop\_REPOS\gk-datasync-frontend\serverless-site\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:31:9)
    at createWebpack (C:\Users\i\Desktop\_REPOS\gk-datasync-frontend\serverless-site\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\webpack-dev-server\index.js:21:36)
    at Object.runWebpackDevServer (C:\Users\i\Desktop\_REPOS\gk-datasync-frontend\serverless-site\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\webpack-dev-server\index.js:47:12)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.project (C:\Users\i\Desktop\_REPOS\gk-datasync-frontend\serverless-site\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js:167:32)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (C:\Users\i\Desktop\_REPOS\gk-datasync-frontend\serverless-site\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\switchMap.js:47:27)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\i\Desktop\_REPOS\gk-datasync-frontend\serverless-site\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:66:18)
    at C:\Users\i\Desktop\_REPOS\gk-datasync-frontend\serverless-site\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeToPromise.js:7:24
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

npm start command:

```
    "start": "webpack -v && ng serve --extra-webpack-config webpack.partial.js -o",
```

webpack.partial config:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
console.log(`partial webpack version loaded:`,webpack.version)

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    //modules: [...],
    fallback: {
      "fs": false,
      "tls": false,
      "net": false,
      "path": false,
      "zlib": false,
      "http": false,
      "https": false,
      "stream": false,
      "crypto": false,
      "mssql": false,
      "assert": false,
      "nodemailer": false,
      "xlsx": false,
      "original-fs": false,
      "url-composer": false, //if get error TS2307: Cannot find module --add here
      //"crypto-browserify": require.resolve('crypto-browserify'), //if you want to use this module also don't forget npm i crypto-browserify 
      "adm-zip": false,
      "assert": false,
      "os": false,
      "axios-ntlm": false,
      "http": false,
      "https": false,
      "stream-http": false,
      "https-browserify": false
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "VERSION": JSON.stringify("4711")
    })
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the webpack error messages (despite them not matching the docs) and I wound up with a working config. Here is what I had to change:

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    //modules: [...],
    resolver:{
    fallback: {
      "fs": false,
      ......
```

Note that resolve has a child of resolv**er** which contains the fallbacks